# get Solana transaction status using Rust

Tags: rust, blockchain, solana

I'm trying to get Solana transaction status using Rust. You can get the transaction status using explorer.solana.com, but I want to get it via code.

There is the get_signature_status function in the Rust SDK: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/client/src/rpc_client.rs#L1119

The function above expect a signature object: https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/0.16.2/src/solana_sdk/signature.rs.html#25

So I tried using it:

```
let sig_s = String::from("...");
let sig: Signature = Signature(sig_s.as_bytes());
let stat = self.client.get_signature_status(&sig);
println!("{:?}", stat);
```

But I get an error of: "constructor is not visible here due to private fields"

I'm trying to understand if there is another way to create Signature object, I guess there should be a way to create Signature object and get its status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you linked to a massively outdated version of the docs (v0.16.2, the latest is v1.9.6). See https://docs.rs/solana-sdk for the latest version.

In the latest version, [`Signature`](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/signature/struct.Signature.html) implements [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/str/trait.FromStr.html) so you can do the following:

```
let sig = Signature::from_str(sig_s).unwrap();
```

And that'll get you a `Signature` you can use.

Comment: Thanks! it does create the Signature object. But when I'm trying to use with: `let stat = self.client.get_signature_statuses(&[sig]);` I get value: [None]. How can I get the txStatus  and confirmations data like in https://api.solscan.io/transaction?tx=2JXYZ9GKNeiVZ3ss1BZYdMxgJvcdqQ3FxcpBp3EBxgGgjTZK8yfpYo7fT94sQ1FSDMGfvj74FpTESEoSJohQcjAf? I'm trying to get number of validations to see if transaction if final.

Comment: It returns None because the get_signature_statuses function checks only recent status and not transaction history